# Set env variable for apache after user input

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I need to pass some dynamic env variables after user input to be used as variables for PHP.

I already had a script which exports the vars enter by the user

```
#!/bin/bash
export APACHE_ENV_VAR0 = $1
export APACHE_ENV_VAR1 = $2
```

After that I check the value and all is OK. Then I set the following in my httpd.conf

```
SetEnv APACHE_ENV_VAR0 ${APACHE_ENV_VAR0}
SetEnv APACHE_ENV_VAR1 ${APACHE_ENV_VAR1}

#Also tried with PassEnv directive
```

The issue is that the output is always false, so it is not finding those vars.

The idea is after I execute the script and set my vars, start httpd and use those vars, but is not working as expected.

My env is a centos, apache2.4 and php5.4

Any idea on how to do this. The user input is required.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is that Apache is starting in a different context as a different user and those environment variables are not set.  A more direct way is to keep a pristine copy of httpd.conf as a template.  Search and replace the variable values you need in it and then start Apache using the modified file.

e.g. in the template file SetEnv APACHE_ENV_VAR0 ^REPLACE_ME^